# Install Ansible collections directly from a git URI with ansible-galaxy

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

The documentation for `ansible-galaxy` indicates the following:

> The ansible-galaxy command comes bundled with Ansible, and you can use it to install roles from Galaxy or directly from a git based SCM. You can also use it to create a new role, remove roles, or perform tasks on the Galaxy website.

I'm trying to figure out how it's possible to install an Ansible collection "*directly from a git based SCM*" as indicated. When I run `ansible-galaxy collections --help`, from Ansible 2.9.1 on MacOS Catalina, I see the following:

```
usage: ansible-galaxy collection install [-h] [-s API_SERVER]
                                         [--api-key API_KEY] [-c] [-v] [-f]
                                         [-i] [-n | --force-with-deps]
                                         [-p COLLECTIONS_PATH]
                                         [-r REQUIREMENTS]
                                         [collection_name [collection_name ...]]

positional arguments:
  collection_name       The collection(s) name or path/url to a tar.gz
                        collection artifact. This is mutually exclusive with
                        --requirements-file.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -s API_SERVER, --server API_SERVER
                        The Galaxy API server URL
  --api-key API_KEY     The Ansible Galaxy API key which can be found at
                        https://galaxy.ansible.com/me/preferences. You can
                        also use ansible-galaxy login to retrieve this key or
                        set the token for the GALAXY_SERVER_LIST entry.
  -c, --ignore-certs    Ignore SSL certificate validation errors.
  -v, --verbose         verbose mode (-vvv for more, -vvvv to enable
                        connection debugging)
  -f, --force           Force overwriting an existing role or collection
  -i, --ignore-errors   Ignore errors during installation and continue with
                        the next specified collection. This will not ignore
                        dependency conflict errors.
  -n, --no-deps         Don't download collections listed as dependencies.
  --force-with-deps     Force overwriting an existing collection and its
                        dependencies.
  -p COLLECTIONS_PATH, --collections-path COLLECTIONS_PATH
                        The path to the directory containing your collections.
  -r REQUIREMENTS, --requirements-file REQUIREMENTS
                        A file containing a list of collections to be
                        installed.
```

I tried specifying a GitHub repository URI for the `-p` parameter, but instead of recognizing a valid URI, `ansible-galaxy` tried to look in a subfolder *named* the URI that I specified.

```
ansible-galaxy collection install -p https://github.com/pcgeek86/ansible-galaxy-test trevor.trevormacos
```

My expectation would be that specifying a GitHub repository URI for the `-p` parameter should properly indicate that I want to install a collection *from that GitHub repository*.

**Question**: How do I instruct `ansible-galaxy` to install an Ansible collection *directly from a GitHub URI*?

Comment: roles and collections are not the same thing. Documentation states you can install roles from SCM. Not collections, a collection can contain roles, but it isn't a role.

Comment: Gotcha, so the answer is "it's not possible?"

Comment: there might be, i have never seen it though, and there is no mention of it in the documentation. thats why i havn't written an answer because there might be, but i have never heard of it.

Comment: Seems like work is in progress in this area ! https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/69154

Answer (score 9):

Since recent Ansible version 2.10 this is now possible.

See: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/69154

To use it you specify similar to roles:

```
collections:
  - name: git@github.com:my_org/private_collections.git#/path/to/collection,devel
  - name: https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws.git
    type: git
    version: 8102847014fd6e7a3233df9ea998ef4677b99248
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a command-line syntax to install role from git repo (e.g. GitHub):

```
ansible-galaxy install git+https://github.com/myorg/ansible-role-example.git
```

To specify branch, append `,mybranch` at the end of the command.