# installing ansible collections from github

Tags: ansible

I have tried to install ansible collection from github. I can not use ansible galaxy because I cannot make the code public.

I tried some public repo:

```
vm:~/ansible/test$ ansible-galaxy collection install git+https://github.com/devroles/ansible_collection_system.git
Process install dependency map
ERROR! Invalid collection name 'git+https', name must be in the format <namespace>.<collection>. Please make sure namespace and collection name contains characters from [a-zA-Z0-9_] only.
```

This does not work but when I use download from ansible galaxy it works.

```
vm:~/ansible/test$ ansible-galaxy collection install devroles.system
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: [Testing inside a docker container, I can't reproduce your problem](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/fb86f7fb3762052992a451e8e6eee646)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ansible version is up-to-date. Installing from git repository is possible since ansible 2.10.

```
collections:
  - name: git@github.com:my_org/private_collections.git#/path/to/collection,devel
  - name: https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws.git
    type: git
    version: 8102847014fd6e7a3233df9ea998ef4677b99248
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/63118089/21268007 and https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/69154